# Diferencia de tiempo de ejecución entre distribuciones Unix

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian

Tengo la siguiente clase que abre procesos para generar claves de cifrado:

```
class KeyGenerator(Process):

def __init__(self,conn):
    Process.__init__(self)
    self.result = []
    self.conn = conn


def run(self):

    for s in range(50000):
        secret = Random.new().read(30)
        hs = SHA256.new()
        hs.update(secret)
        key = hs.digest()
        self.result.append(key) 
    self.conn.send(self.result)
```

En el main abro 5 procesos, por lo que al final genero 1M de claves. Ahora bien, corriendo este código en 3 máquinas virtuales con las mismas características en cuanto a memoria y número de procesadores (y las tres con arquitectura amd64), pero con distintas distribuciones Unix obtengo diferentes resultados de tiempo de ejecución:

**Kali Linux (Rolling)**: 0.8795 segundos.

**Ubuntu Server 16.04**: 2.1523 segundos.

**Debian 9.2.1**: 2.2234 segundos.

Entiendo la mínima diferencia entre Ubuntu y Debian, que incluso podríamos considerar despreciable. Ahora bien, Kali está basado en Debian, y a pesar de ello obtiene un tiempo sustancialmente menor al obtenido con la máquina virtual Debian.

¿Por qué ocurre esto?¿Hay algún tipo de mejora conocida en la implementación del kernel utilizado en Kali que mejore los tiempos de ejecución a la hora de ejecutar código interpretado como el de Python?

Comment: ¿Kurosh D en los tres casos se usa la misma versión de cpython?

Comment: Sí, en todos los casos utilizo Python 2.7.

Comment: Kali tiene por defecto deshabilitados los servicios de red, no como ubuntu/debian que ejecutan estos servicios por defecto. Posiblemente, si paras todos los servicios, deberían equipararse tiempos. Casi se puede asegurar que no se trata de una mejor implementación de python, pero no es posible responderte sin tener información concreta de los entornos con los que estás probando.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Qué información concreta requerirías? Y hay alguna manera de obtener la distribución Linux usada en Kali pero sin todas las herramientas de pentesting?

Comment: @KuroshD. Se necesitaría pasar algún *profiler* sobre el código, alguna monitorización del sistema en los tres entornos, conocer qué configuración concreta tiene cada uno (sistema de ficheros, gestión de memoria y de procesos, etc). Sobre todo si los kernels están optimizados para virtualización y para x64, ya que así los usas. Hay linux ligeros que puedes configurar desde cero (gentoo, arch,...), o puedes usar alpine linux como es habitual usar con docker.